# Where can I download a trial version of Lightroom 6?

Tags: adobe, lightroom-6

I would like to evaluate the features of the software Adobe Lightroom 6. Especially the hardware acceleration and if it works with my dated computer<sup>1</sup>.

I worked myself through the Adobe website to the download page, which states that I can click to download trial versions of the listed products.

I then click Lightroom CC and eventually I end up at the shopping basket, which allows me to add Lightroom 6 to it.

However, I can only add full versions or upgrades. **How can I download a trial version?**

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm not interested in any data sheets or program specifications that state that my hardware *should be* supported. I want to see and try it myself.

Comment: From what country are you accessing the Adobe site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't have a Lightroom 6 trial version, only a Lightroom CC trial version.**

From Adobe itself (https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/lightroom-trial-ccm.html), you have to **install the Creative Cloud desktop app** when you are **logged in with a free Membership account**. Then, you should be able to download it.

You can download the Creative Cloud desktop app here : https://creative.adobe.com/products/creative-cloud

Once you have the Creative Cloud app with Lightroom installed, you should see something like it :

[image: Creative Cloud app]

(instead of "Trial Expired", you will get "Trial version").

**You can "transform" Lightroom CC into Lightroom 6 only after having bought a Lightroom 6 Serial Number** (https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/serialize-lightroom-cc-trial-to-activate-as-lightroom-6.html).

By the way, after buying Lightroom CC, a badly configured DNS server might prevent Adobe from verifying that you have indeed bought the software and it is still considered as a "trial"... until you configure properly your DNS server :)

Comment: See post #15 of this thread for a possible workaround. Once you have the CC trial downloaded, rather than using the auto installer, go into the folder created on your desktop by the extracted download and run the setup.exe inside the folder.    http://www.lightroomforums.net/showthread.php?25012-Is-LR6-standalone-available-as-a-standalone-download